# How to serialize relational models as JSON in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, active-model-serializers

Say I have a basic `User` model:

```
# Name                          | Type               | Attributes
# ----------------------------- | ------------------ | ---------------------------
# **`id`**                      | `bigint`           | `not null, primary key`
# **`email`**                   | `string`           | `default(""), not null`
# **`encrypted_password`**      | `string`           | `default(""), not null`
```

A user can have many companies they manage. So `user.rb` contains:

```
has_many :company_permissions

has_many :companies, -> { distinct }, through: :company_permissions
```

`Company` is pretty simple:

```
# Name               | Type               | Attributes
# ------------------ | ------------------ | ---------------------------
# **`id`**           | `bigint`           | `not null, primary key`
# **`description`**  | `text`             |
# **`name`**         | `string`           |
```

`User` and `Company` are related by a Rails relational model called `CompanyPermission`:

```
# Name              | Type               | Attributes
# ----------------- | ------------------ | ---------------------------
# **`id`**          | `bigint`           | `not null, primary key`
# **`name`**        | `string`           |
# **`company_id`**  | `bigint`           | `not null`
# **`user_id`**     | `bigint`           | `not null`
```

A permission's `name` can be `read`, `write`, or `delete`. If a user has more than 1 permission (e.g. read and write) then there are 2 relational models.

A user can see a JSON response of their current companies:

```
class CredentialsController < AuthorizedController
  def me
    render json: current_user, include: %i[companies]
  end
end
```

This produces output like:

```
{
    "id": 676,
    "email": "email1@example.com",
    "companies": [{
        "id": 786,
        "name": "Some Company",
        "description": "Some Company Description"
    }]
}
```

As you can see, the user doesn't know which permissions they have. I'd like to include the information from `CustomerPermission.name` here, perhaps something like:

```
{
    "id": 676,
    "email": "email1@example.com",
    "companies": [{
        "id": 786,
        "name": "Some Company",
        "description": "Some Company Description",
        "permissions": ["read", "write"] # <------- I want this
    }]
}
```

Do I need to write an `ActiveModel::Serializer` from scratch for this? Or is there some other way to easily include this detail from the relational model in the JSON output?

Comment: Hey there! You can use https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi, it's quite easy to make it work and it works much faster than active model serializer

Comment: Can it be done without AMS? Yes definitely. Just loop through the records and set the companies attribute or select an array aggregate when fetching the records. Is it going to be easier than just using AMS? No probably not.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi](https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi) as Alex mentioned in the comment above.

Keep in mind, this does change the structure to adhere to [Google's JSON:API standard](https://jsonapi.org/). Everything will be nested within the "attributes" property. And when you use `include` method, it won't include all the data from, for example, Companies - just the id.

Essentially, you need to create a custom method and violate the standard in order to achieve that, but it made total sense in my situations to do that opposed to making multiple API calls.

Create a serializer for your User and Company models, and within that you can define a custom attribute block like:

```rb
# app/serializers/user_serializer.rb
class UserSerializer
  include FastJsonapi::ObjectSerializer

  attribute :companies do |user|
    CompanySerializer.new(user.companies).serializable_hash[:data]
  end
end

# app/serializers/company_serializer.rb
class CompanySerializer
  include FastJsonapi::ObjectSerializer

  attribute :permissions do |company|
    company.company_permissions.map{|perm| perm.name}
  end
end
```

Hope that helps :)